# Is it d^3V or dV when integrating for volume (triple integral)?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, volume

In a volume integral dxdydz is shortened to dV. I have also seen d^3V. So dcubed V. What is the correct way to write it, or are both correct?

Comment: The cube is typical of physicist's literature, to ease dimensional analysis.

Comment: So it´s just a way of writing.

Comment: In the setting of differential geometry, it is correct to write $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$. Anything else ($dx\,dy\,dz, d^3x, d^3V, dV$ and others) is a shorthand, for brevity and readability.

Comment: @Magnetar: Yes, just a way of writing. It can be nice to use a coordinate-independent symbol like $dV$, so one can write the change of variable formula in the form $dV=\ldots$. The $d^3V$ incorporates dimensional analysis in the picture, like I have already said in the previous comment.